# Prevent background process from showing up on Dock

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java application. For some tasks, I run another JVM instance in parallel using `ProcessBuilder`. i.e. my main application starts another JVM instance using `Process` and then both communicate using I/O.

But on the `Dock` on Mac, it shows both the process:
[image]

I do not want that, as the other process only does the back-end work and is not required to be shown up front. Also it is a risk as he can manually force quit the another process easily.

What should be done to make sure it runs on background and doesn't show itself on dock

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your back-end processor truly does not need any screen resources then the simplest thing to do is too launch the new JVM in *headless* mode:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true com.bl.ProcessMain
```

Answer (score 6):

To enable it globally instead of adding the option to each process, set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable like this in your .bashrc/.zshrc start up script.

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'

Reference here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html