# Prevent java app name from appearing in menu bar and process dock on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I'm starting a runnable jar from a java app ( also headless runnable jar). 
Tried both `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and `ProcesBuilder` method. The process gets launched just fine, but on the Mac ( 10.6 ) it shows the name of the jar  I'm starting in the main menu bar and also puts in the dock Is there a way to prevent that ? Interestingly, if you start a jar with java -jar  from the command line the jar name does not appear in the menu bar or process dock.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Andy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent background process from showing up on Dock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742976/prevent-background-process-from-showing-up-on-dock)

Answer (score 32):

To enable it globally instead of adding the option to each process, set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable like this in your .bashrc/.zshrc start up script.

```sh
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
```

Reference here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html

Comment: Not all Java applications respect `JAVA_OPTS`, and when they do it's because there's code in the application's launcher shell script to handle it.  A `JAVA_OPTS` setting won't affect anything you run directly with `java -jar`, or when you double-click a JAR file in Finder.

Comment: I corrected it and verified it works. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 11):

Are you passing `java.awt.headless=true`?  Try adding this to your process:

`java -Djava.awt.headless=true`